# Laravel - How to use the package.json version attribute as process.env.APP_VERSION?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How to use the package.json version attribute as process.env.APP_VERSION ?
Alternativ :
how to put the package.json version attribute into config('APP_VERSION') helper ?

Comment: Are you trying to use it from a blade or a vue component?

Comment: I can accept all solution ! Here I try to use it from my app.js and/or my store.js

Comment: If you have a solution to write package version into a <meta> I'm interested too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To access package.json version try:**

```js
const { version } = require('./package.json');
```

**Bonus:**

To create the meta tag with js, check [this](https://gist.github.com/robertkowalski/4206422).

**Getting .env data from a Vue component**
Use:

```
MIX_MY_VAR=var
```

Access:

```js
process.env.MIX_MY_VAR
```

Comment: I was not aware that a "require" imported code at compile time.
Stupidly I thought that the only way to achieve this was to go through the "process.env". Thank you !